# Directional derivatives involving tetrads turn into covariant derivatives?

Tags: general-relativity

In the tetrad formalism we define four vectors $e_{(a)}^i$ labelled by $a=1,2,3,4$ with components $i=0,1,2,3$ , such that they are related to the metric tensor by

$$e_{(a)i}e^{(a)}_j=g_{ij}$$

while the label indices are raised and lowered by the auxiliary metric (equivalent to Minkowksi metric)

$$\eta_{(a)(b)}\equiv e_{(a)}^i e_{(b)i}$$

We can define a directional derivative in the direction of a tetrad by

$$e_{(a)}=e_{(a)}^i\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}$$

with coordinates $x^i$ as parametrized by the metric $g_{ij}$.
When such a directional derivative is acting on a vector quantity expressed in tetrad notation $A_{(a)}=e_{(a)}^jA_j$, apparently the result turns out to be in terms of covariant derivatives $\nabla_i$:

$$e_{(b)}^i\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}A_{(a)}=e_{(b)}^i(e_{(a)}^j\nabla_iA_j+A_k\nabla_i e_{(a)}^k)$$

I wonder how the covariant derivative appears in the above? Naively it seems like it should be the partial derivative.

Comment: What do you mean by $\nabla_i$ is it schematically speaking, $\nabla = \partial + \Gamma + \omega$, where $\omega$ is the spin connection or $\nabla = \partial + \Gamma$

Comment: @GonencMogol I think it is $\nabla=\partial+\Gamma$.

Comment: @GonencMogol btw, this statement can be found in eq. (251) of the book "The mathematical theory of black holes" by Chandrasekhar.

Comment: This is exactly the same as in the case of coordinates, and no mentioning of tetrads. How do you find the derivative of $\frac{\partial}{\partial y}$ in the direction of $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$? You need a connection.

Comment: @MBN Thank you for pointing this out! I agree, but could you elaborate a bit more on where such a $\frac{\partial}{\partial y}$ is in this example? As far as I can see, $e_{(a)}^j$ is a vector of components, not derivatives, and $A_j$ as well. I find it intuitively clear that a derivative of a vector quantity should involve covariant derivative, but I'm trying to see this more rigorously in the notation without invoking intuition.

Comment: The elements of the tetrad are vector fields. Use different notations, say $X, Y, Z, W$. What is the derivative of $Y$ in the direction of $X$? You need a covariant derivative for that. The usual notation is $\nabla_XY$.

Comment: @MBN I agree, $e_{(a)}$ and $A$ would be vector fields, but $e_{(a)}^j$ and $A_j$ are just components that would multiply the basis vectors $\frac{\partial}{\partial x^j}$. It looks like the expression in the question above is in terms of the components only...

Comment: @Kagaratsch When the components multiply the basis vectors and you sum, you get the tetrad vector that's what the expression $e_{(a)}=e^i_{(a)}\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}$ means.

Comment: @MBN yes, I agree.